# Integration of jira with nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, jira

I try to use the `rest api` of `JIRA` with `nodejs`. I want to login, list issues, get issues, resolve issues. But I have problems. I stuck at the beginning.

Firstly, I checked my JIRA version. 
It says;

```
Bug tracking and project tracking for software development powered by Atlassian JIRA (v4.2.1)
```

Then to be able to see the documentation of this version's rest api, 
I navigate to; https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/4.2.1/

When I try to go to the link;
https://MYHOSTNAME/jira/rest/api/2.0.alpha1/version

it throws an error as;

```
HTTP Status 404 - /jira/rest/api/2.0.alpha1/version
```

I don't understand, does my JIRA version is not supported? What am I missing?

Comment: I've had good results using the `jira-client` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incomplete `URL`, you need to give the `version id`

Try to use this `URL`

```
/api/2.0.alpha1/version/{id}
```

Where `id` is your version number

> 404(Not Found)- Returned if the version does not exist or the currently authenticated user does not have permission to view it.
>
> 200(success) - application/json

[Source URL](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/4.3/#id73157)

Comment: I added the version at the end but it still gives me the same error:/

Comment: Can you show me, how are you making the  URL with version number? As per doc it should work